# Linking two objects with large amount of records

Tags: apex, trigger

I'm trying to link a record from one object with another based on a field present on both that **should** have the same value. If both object records have the same value, then I want to update the case with the found contact.

```
trigger LinkPersonAccount on Case (before insert, before update) {

    map<String, Case> mapConcatIdToCase = new map<String, Case>(); 
    List<Case> updateList = new List<Case>();

    // Map concat Id to case 
    for(Case c : Trigger.new) 
    {
        if(c.ContactId == null)
        {
            mapConcatIdToCase.put(c.Concat_Id__c, c); 
        }
    }

    // now based on concat ids query account records and match
    for(Account objAccount: [SELECT Id, Concat_Id__c FROM Account WHERE Concat_Id__c IN: mapConcatIdToCase.keyset()])
    {
        System.Debug('Match!: ' + mapConcatIdToCase.get(objAccount.Concat_Id__c ).Id + ' | ' + objAccount.Id);
        // If both fields match then add objAccount.Id to Case Contact field
    }

    update updateList;

}
```

I recieve the following error on the account query, which makes sense (each object has 500k+ records):

`System.QueryException: Non-selective query against large object type (more than 200000 rows). Consider an indexed filter or contact salesforce.com about custom indexing.` I can filter more, but I'm not able to filter the records below 200K so I need another solution.

Is there any way I can marry the two object records up based on a common field without hitting a limit?

Thanks

Comment: Where are you getting this exception. Can you highlight the line because I doubt its SOQL on Account.

Comment: `for(Account objAccount: [SELECT Id, Concat_Id__c FROM Account WHERE Concat_Id__c IN: mapConcatIdToCase.keyset()])` is the line corresponding the error. We're using person accounts so that explains the 200k+ amount.

Comment: Should it not be if(c.ContactId != null)

Comment: @paul You mean when populating the map? It checks to see if a case is linked with an account (via contact lookup), and then if it's not found use the concat_Id__c field to find the account record to link it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[One common cause of this is searching against a null value. So, you should first consider excluding values where Concat_Id__c is null. But I don't think that this is your problem here.]

The overall problem is that when you have a lot of records, SF needs to be able to run the query in a way that brings the number of results down to a reasonable level by filtering on an indexed field.

If Concat_Id__c is not a formula, then set it as an External Id. This will cause SF to build an index on that field and allow you to query against a large group of records.

However, I suspect Concat_Id__c is the concatenation of two Ids using a formula. In which case, you can't index on it directly.

If Concat_Id__c is a formula like F1__c + '-' + F2__c, then you should use F1__c and F2__c in your query (along with Concat_Id__c). If they are Id fields, then SF will index them by default.

So, when you loop through the Cases, populating mapConcatIdToCase you would also populate some sets, f1Vals and f2Vals, with the values for F1__c and F2__c from the Case.

Then, make your query into

[SELECT Id, Concat_Id__c FROM Account WHERE Concat_Id__c IN: mapConcatIdToCase.keyset() AND F1__c IN :f1Vals AND F2__c IN :f2Vals]

This might seem redundant because (F1__c IN :f1Vals AND F2__c IN :f2Vals) implies that Concat_Id__c IN: mapConcatIdToCase.keyset(). But, SF has indexes on F1__c and F2__c so it can filter down the number of results with those, then pick out the actual results you need by looking at Concat_Id__c.

Comment: Thanks Aidan, the concatenation ID is created with FirstName + LastName + PersonEmail.
 These are standard fields for person accounts, which aren't indexed. Would you still suggest searching by these fields?

Comment: In that case, there's not much to be gained by searching on FirstName LastName and PersonEmail, as you can't index them. Is Concat_Id__c a formula though? If it is, you could turn it into a text field that you populate in a before update, before insert trigger. Then mark that text as external id (which will index on it), then your query should be OK